# Por que width e height não funciona neste caso?

Tags: css

Bem, testei de várias formas, mudando o elemento `span`pelo `h6`, pelo `strong`, e outros, e nada! Não  teve jeito, até agora, de formatar o `width`e `height` de um elemento dentro da tag `<p>`. Será que o CSS não aceita, é isso? Ou o que falta?. Segue o código:
PS: percebam que o meu intento é deixar o número "1" em um círculo/caixa com 30x30px, só isso.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<style>

p {
font-family: 'Lobster Two', cursive; font-size:18pt;
}

.x {
width:30px; height:30px; border:1px solid black; line-height:30px; border-radius:50%;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>
<p><span class="x">1</span>A raposa lançou-se esbaforida sobre o pássaro.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Você está tentando colocar largura em um elemento inline. se puser um `display:inline-block;text-align:center;` no `.x` ou mesmo `display:block`, mudará o comportamento do elemento. O `inline-block` é mais interessante nesse caso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está tentando colocar largura em um elemento inline.

De acordo com a documentação, a propriedade `width` vale para todos os elementos **exceto conteúdo inline não substituido**, que por acaso é exatamente a semântica do `span`.

Para o efeito desejado, você precisa mudar o comportamento do `span` para que ele funcione como bloco, usando a propriedade `display`.

Pode usar `block` ou melhor ainda `inline-block` neste caso, permitindo que o elemento acompanhe o fluxo do texto.

Veja aplicado ao seu código:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    p {
        font-family: 'Lobster Two', cursive; font-size:18pt;
    }  
    .x {
        display:inline-block;text-align:center; /* só acrescentamos esta linha */
        width:30px; height:30px; border:1px solid black; line-height:30px; border-radius:50%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <p><span class="x">1</span> A raposa lançou-se esbaforida sobre o pássaro.</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note que aproveitamos e usamos um `text-align:center` para deixar o número no meio do círculo.

Saiba mais na MDN:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/width

> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/display

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="x">
<p><span>1</span>A raposa lançou-se esbaforida sobre o pássaro.</p>
</div>
```

Tente com isso